# Not able to connect https server using SharpSvn in C# , Could not connect to server error

Tags: c#, https, sharpsvn

I am developing Windows application in VS2010. I am using SharpSVN to connect with subversion repository. I have tried to get the repository items using `svnClient.GetList(targetUri, out list);` function. It is working fine for local(`file\\:`) repository. When I try to connect the https server, it is giving error.

I have used to sample https server given in codespeces. I have tried in tortoiseSVN also to connect. It is saying "could not connect to server". And I have tried through C# and getting the same error.

Please see below for https server url and username and password

```
https://svn.codespaces.com/cw/com_codespaces_api_net

username: api_guest
password Password1
```

below code I have used to connect.

```
using (SvnClient svnClient = new SvnClient())
  {
svnClient.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("api_guest", "Password1");

                SvnTarget targetUri = new SvnUriTarget(new Uri(sourcePath));
                var list = new Collection<SvnListEventArgs>();                
                svnClient.GetList(targetUri, out list);
}
```

Error Message:

```
OPTIONS of 'https://svn.codespaces.com/cw/com_codespaces_api_net': could not connect to server (https://svn.codespaces.com)"
```

I have searched for solution in Google. I am not able to find any help.